# If I make a Thread in a controller action, do I need to wrap the inner code in an executor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, rails-activerecord

I have a controller action where I make a thread with `Thread.new`.

Do I need to wrap the inner code with an executor?

I *think* this part of the docs is saying I should "if your application manually delegates work to other threads, such as via Thread.new or Concurrent Ruby features that use thread pools, you should immediately wrap the block" https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html#wrapping-application-code